# Sequelize layering AND/OR operators

Tags: mysql, orm, sequelize.js

I want to check if a relationship exists between two users by looking for either a relationship of (user1 AND user2) OR (user2 AND user1)

Right now I have it set up as:

```
db.friends.findOne({
          where: {
            [Op.or]: {
              [Op.and]: [{ userID1: uid1 }, { userID2: uid2 }],
              [Op.and]: [{ userID1: uid2 }, { userID2: uid1 }],
            },
          },
        });
```

If only one of the Op.and operators is used it works for that "and" if the uid's are in the right order but, if both Op.and are there, it only finds the relationship of the second and statement.

Am I ordering the ops wrong? Why won't it find the relationship regardless of who's ID is 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

You used an object instead of an array as a value of `Op.or` that's why it does not work properly:

```js
[Op.or]: [
  { [Op.and]: [{ userID1: uid1 }, { userID2: uid2 }] },
  { [Op.and]: [{ userID1: uid2 }, { userID2: uid1 }] },
]
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for catching it! I had to also add {} around the inner two [] statements to make it work.

```[Op.or]: [

  {[Op.and]: [{ userID1: uid1 }, { userID2: uid2 }]},

 {[Op.and]: [{ userID1: uid2 }, { userID2: uid1 }]},
],```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll fix the answer right away

Comment: It's done, you can check it